# Does GWT app work well in Android browser?

Tags: android, gwt

I am planning a web app using GWT. How well will it be supported on mobile devices like iphone, android?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The iPhone and Android browser are both based on WebKit, as is Chrome. GWT is cross-platform and works on WebKit based browsers, but as always it is essential to test your Web app on all the major device variations that you plan to support to ensure it works as expected (for example iPhone 3GS and iPhone 2G for performance testing, Google Nexus One and HTC Tattoo for large/small screen testing) - Services like the [Device Anywhere Test Suite](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing.html) can make this process more financially viable if your development is not focused on smart-phones.

There is also the [GWT Mobile WebKit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) project, which seeks to add mobile device features into GWT. This might be worth considering if you require smart-phone specific functions like geolocation data or client-side database access...

Answer (score 4):

Nope, not at all. Scrolling is one of the issues. More details http://androidanswer.com/questions/82/gwt-app-android-browser-no-way-to-scroll-or-no-scrollbar-scrolling-doesnt-work

Comment: Yeap, default android browser on v4.0.4 does not support the GWT function widget.getElement().setScrollTop() at all. While other browsers for android like FireFox and Chrome work.

Answer (score 2):

GWT compiles Java to JavaScript. It optimizes using techniques similar to a C++ compiler, so performance of applications will be comparable to native JavaScript applications. It does encourage the generation of large programs because it makes including new code simpler for Java developers.

I would be interested to see benchmarks comparing GWT performance with native JavaScript performance, but my view is that GWT compiled apps run at an adequate speed on the Android browser.